# Mobile view by text length - bootstrap

Tags: html

I need to write html page, that represent customer requests, (I do it with collapse). but a have a problem in mobile view. if the title too long, the line break to 2 lines,and I want the status always aligned right after title.
In addition I need to limit the number of characters in the title and add 3 points if needed.
How can I do this?
Example:
[image: short title]
[image: medium title]
[image: long title]

The HTML here:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-1" >1.5.16</div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs" >235266 -</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4" >Title</div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs" >1.7.16</div>
                        <div style="float:left;" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 hidden-md">| Status</div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this class truncate to title  and 
this css
.truncate { width: 150px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
and you can give 'pull-right' class to status for align right

Comment: Thank you for your response, but if I want the title first to try to enter the 2 lines and if its too long - there will be 3 points, how can I do that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pnb2ksp8/1/ check this fiddle you have too do this using by pseudo-element